# How do people test their [RequireHttps] attribute in a Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ssl, asp.net-web-api

**Quick version**

I'm sure many people have implemented a `[RequireHttps]` SSL check of some description (message handler, attribute, whatever) at some point in their Web API development. How do you guys and gals test that it works correctly both in terms of success and failure?

**Not so quick version**

I'm developing a REST service in a OWIN self-hosted ASP.NET Web API 2. I have already successfully secured the service with SSL and have implemented a custom `[RequireHttps]` attribute (derived from the answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265710/require-ssl-in-webapi)).

In the case when the client is calling the correct URL (e.g. `https://my.server.com/api/values`), if I add a breakpoint in the attribute definition, the debugger correctly breaks in the code (just calls the base and all is well, as expected).

The question is: **how can I exercise the failure scenario for this attribute**, such that the attribute code will return an error response *without interfering with other server processes*?

My Web API service listens on base address `https://+:9443/`. I've tried removing the **s** such that I connect to `http://my.server.com:9443/api/values`, but I get an error response status 502 (connection failed) after about a minute's timeout. Fair enough I suppose, but I was actually hoping to return a response ("SSL required") from my `[RequireHttps]` attribute.

Then I've tried creating the following `StartOptions` object:

```
var options = new StartOptions();
options.Urls.Add("https://+:9443/"); // listen on port 9443 with SSL
options.Urls.Add("http://+:80/");  // listen to standard HTTP port 80
```

and passing it to the WebApp like this:

```
WebApp.Start<Startup>(options)
```

Again, this didn't work when I connected to `http://my.server.com:9443/api/values`, but it worked when I connected to `http://my.server.com:80/api/values`.

However, this is not what I want to do. My production server hosts both secure (HTTPS) and insecure (HTTP on port 80) resources so my code will intercept legitimate calls to other processes that rely on port 80 and tell them to reconnect via https, which is wrong.

Can someone please advise on what options I have? Is there even a point to have `[RequireHttps]` given my situation, as it never seems to do anything useful?

Comment: I don't understand why you think your code would be called for "other processes".  If you're using an attribute decorated on a single class or method, it would only get called when that class or method was used.

Comment: I was slightly confused myself. You're correct that if I use an attribute on a class or method, then the code would only be called if the class or method was used. But what about in the case of a message handler? I was hoping to catch this early in the pipeline (message handlers are processed before filters). Then, "other processes" on the server might become broken. Or am I confusing myself again?

Comment: I would suggest that you shouldn't be doing anything that needs authentication in a message handler, Your handler should defer to an action that is authenticated.  And if you do, then I would suggest implement an authentication handler first that chains to your handler.  Something like this. http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/30/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-MessageHandler

Comment: The RequireHttps action doesn't require any authentication, so I'm not sure what you mean. There are 2 ways to do implement RequireHttps -- as a message handler or as a filter attribute (both explained in the SO question and its answers that I linked). I'm trying to figure out what steps I need to do to test both the success case and the failure case (make it return an error), without affecting any other services that may be running on the server on other ports, schemes, etc. In the end, I would prefer to use the handler as it's executed earlier than the attribute filter.

Comment: Message Handlers only execute if it's a WebAPI call.  They don't execute for MVC calls or ASP.NET calls or anything else, so I'm still not clear by what you mean by "other server processes".

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can't be done.  Basically, you're trying to do the same thing as typing

```
http:443//www.google.com
```

Notice how that doesn't work either

The problem is that you're trying to access an http protocol over an SSL protocol port, and that is what's failing.  Your code for the RequireHttps doesn't even get to execute because the request can't even be processed through IIS.

Comment: I'm aware of that, it's fair enough (as I said in my post). My question was more about *how* I can test the code, not so much about *why* it doesn't work in that particular case. I've edited the post to make my question clearer (and perhaps quicker for people to read).

Comment: @djikay - That's the point, you can't test it, because it doesn't work.  It can't do anything.  You cannot connect to an SSL port with a non-ssl protocol.  It will fail.

Comment: I can't find anything that says it's legal to put the port where you've tried to put it in "http:443//www.google.com".  I'd guess that's why it doesn't work.  In fact, if you put the port in the standard (and possibly only allowed) place, as http ://www.google.com:443 (without the space, which I've put in for SO formatting reasons) , then it *does* work.  (Though I'm sure that's something Google have implemented.)

Comment: @mwardm - Yeah, that was a typo.  It should be `http://www.google.com:443/` - and no, it doesn't work, at least not in IE or chrome. Maybe whatever browser you're using is correcting it, or you have a plugin of some sort, or autocorrect is replacing it with an https

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Okay, I'll have to agree that it doesn't work!  (I was in Chrome and it looked to be working.  I was being careful about allowing it to auto-anything the URL, but on further investigation apparently still not careful enough!)