# What Http status we should use for Web Api/Restful requires https

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api, https, http-status-codes

I am designing a WebApi that requires Https request.

If client use http protocol, The API service will reject the request and return an http error status.

I am thinking to return 400 - Bad request. I found this post on SO: [Require SSL in WebApi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265710/require-ssl-in-webapi)

someone return 403 - Forbidden or 404 - Not Found for this purpose.

What status you think we should use? Thank you!

Comment: `HttpStatusCode.BadRequest`. This is used when no other error code is suitable.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using "System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden" or 403 . Just add a reason phrase that says "HTTPS Required" .